# Windows! Path String \ gets converted to \\\\

Tags: python, python-3.x, tarfile, pathlib

This Code works just fine on Ubuntu and MacOs but gives me headaches on windows.

```
manifest_zip_path = Path(zip_path).name / Path("manifest")
tar = tarfile.open(zip_path, "r:gz")
f = tar.extractfile(str(manifest_zip_path))
```

There is a Path object which I convert to a string.
In Debugger the string is shown as "abcde.tar.gz\manifest".
When I pass it to the extractfile function I get:

```
KeyError: filename 'abcde.tar.gz\\\\manifest' not found
```

Where do these 4 backslashes come from? The conversion has to happen inside the tarfile method? Is this an Error from them and if not how can I resolve it?

Comment: Possibly '\' are escaped so there are only two. The other question is why those two are here, I'm not python programmer, probably something with operator "/"

Comment: Yeah I thought so too. But because I pass the correct string in the tarfile library method the error most definitely  has to come from there

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem but wasn't able to - what is the value of zip_path prior to using Path?

Comment: The value is and should be something like "user/backup/abcde.tar.gz". But I resolved the issue, you can look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by doing this

```
f = tar.extractfile(str(manifest_zip_path).replace("\\", "/"))
```

tarfile library doesn't like backslashes apparently.